# Google Charts - Stacked BarCharts with dates on x-axis

Tags: javascript, date, charts

I have a data set which represents expenses, like this:

```
[{
    '1.1.2012': [{
        'name': 'Company 1',
        'costs': '400'
    }, {
        'name': 'Company 2',
        'costs': 500
    }],
    '2.1.2012': [{
        'name': 'Company 3',
        'costs': '1000'
    }, {
        'name': 'Company 4',
        'costs': 100
    }]
}]
```

My goal is to display a Stacked Bar Chart using Google's Chart API. I would like the X-Axis to represent the days on which the expenses occur, and the y-axis should represent the amounting costs.

It seems that Google doesn't like it if I use my own labels for the x-axis, and all I found to use dates was this: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline, which doesn't apply to the bar chart.

Another issue I'm worried about is that the graph should display the expenses for the next 14 days, so there could be a monthly or even yearly overlap.

Any pointers how I need to pass my data to the `arrayToDataTable()` function Google provides?

Thank you so much for your help!